# Java Regex: Match any words word and must contain a certain work but except one word

Tags: java, regex

I need a Java regex to match any words except a certain word and at the same time contain another word.

For example, the string cannot contain `Apple`, but must have `Peach`.

```
Apple and Peach - Not match
Peach and Apple- Not match
Peach - Match 
Three Peach - Match 
Peach is good - Match 
Peach is good, but Apple is bad - Not match
```

i.e. `Apple` **and** `Peach` cannot appear in a string.

I've got this code so far.

```
^(?!(?:Apple)$)Peach$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the following regex if you want to match the whole sentence:

```
^(?!.*Apple).*Peach.*$
```

**demo:** https://regex101.com/r/G6RdPO/2/

Also if the case is not relevant then you can change the regex into:

```
(?i)^(?!.*Apple).*Peach.*$
```

Last but not least, it is not clear in your question about what should be done with `peaches`, `apples` and `pineapples` (that contain `apple`). If you do not want to take them into account use:

```
(?i)^(?!.*\bApple\b).*\bPeach\b.*$
```

**demo:** https://regex101.com/r/G6RdPO/5

```
Apple and Peach - Not match
Peach and Apple- Not match
Peach - Match 
Three Peach - Match 
Peach is good - Match 
Peach is good, but Apple is bad - Not match
Nothing - Not match
Peaches are good - Not match
Apples an Peaches - Not match
Pineapple and Peach - Match
```

If you want to take also their plurals into account:

```
(?i)^(?!.*\bApple(?:s)?\b).*\bPeach(?:es)?\b.*$
```

**demo:**  https://regex101.com/r/G6RdPO/4

```
Apple and Peach - Not match
Peach and Apple- Not match
Peach - Match
Three Peach - Match
Peach is good - Match
Peach is good, but Apple is bad - Not match
Nothing - Not Match
Peaches are good - Match
Apples an Peaches - Not match
Pineapple and Peach - Match
```

Comment: That is awesome. It works and thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `.*` to match any characters between the start of the string and the keyword you're looking for:

```
^(?!.*Apple).*Peach
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/t3Dz4E/1

Comment: Your regex will not match the whole line and it will stop as soon as it encounters `Peach`, you should add `.*$` after `Peach` to get the whole thing.

Comment: `.*$` is wholly redundant.